VBA - how to copy a range from one sheet to another using its name?
I need to copy a range from one sheet (every time the same range from the same sheet)
for example range a1:a100 from sheet named 'Start' to another sheet (cell b10:b110) with a name picked from the list.
So destination sheet is called 'X', and I have a dropdown list with all the sheets name (so 'X';"XI';"XII' etc), and when I choose X from the list and run macro,
it copy the range (a1:a100) from Start to X (b10:b110), when pick XI from the list and run macro, it copy the same range from Start to (b10:b110) XI... any ideas?

Is dropdown list a data validation on cell or control (Form or ActiveX) on worksheet?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


Assuming the dropdown list is created using data validation in cell D1 on the source sheet.

Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim desSht As String
    ' assuming the dropdown list is data validation on cell D1, modify as need
    desSht = Sheets("Start").Range("D1").Value
    If SheetExists(desSht) Then
        ' Copy cells
        Sheets("Start").Range("A1:A100").Copy Sheets(desSht).Range("B10")
        ' Copy values
        ' Sheets(desSht).Range("B10:B110").Value = Sheets("Start").Range("A1:A100").Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Sheet " & desSht & " does NOT exists."
    End If
End Sub

Function SheetExists(strName As String, Optional wBook As Workbook)
    Dim sh As Object
    If wBook Is Nothing Then Set wBook = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sh = wBook.Sheets(strName)
    SheetExists = (Err = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

